# USB Flash drive size usage discrepancy

Tags: xubuntu, files, usb-drive

I've got a 68gb thumb drive with 52gb of stuff on it and I've got 9gb remaining to add, but I can't do so because Thunar says there's insufficient space. Hitting properties shows this: [image: this]

I've unhidden folders, deleted what I can, and emptied the trash. Graphical disk maps shows the files I have and doesn't reveal anything that would explain the mystery extra.

Does anyone have any ideas what the hell's going on here?

Thanks

edit: new pic[image: pic2]

Comment: edit: gparted also thinks there's only ~2.7gb left, all in one partition

Comment: so is it possible you could provide us a screenshot of what gparted sees?

Comment: It could be due to the problem with the flash memory. If some of it gets unreadable, then the real capacity of the thumb drive would diminish.

Comment: @ThomasW. - pic added with all the info inc graphical disk map. at:mikewhatever: it's a pretty new drive... any way I can check to see if this is the case? 
Cheers gents.

Answer (score 0):

> I've got a 68gb thumb drive with 52gb of stuff on it

No, you likely purchased a 64GB thumb drive.  USB thumb drives are typically issued in powers of 2... (so 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, etc.).  How you get to 67GB volume is likely a larger drive that's damaged.

Secondly, you probably have hidden files and folders and such in the dot-hidden folders - those take up space too.

Thirdly, `gparted` gives you the more accurate file usage statistics, so you've got extra files in there, likely stuff you deleted previously.

> Does anyone have any ideas what is going on here?

There's several confusions you're making.  First, the size of a thumb drive is ***theoretical***.  That is, a 64GB thumb drive may actually have only usable space of 62ish GB.  They can't guarantee you the full space.  Secondly, as stated in comments, you may have damage that reduces the actual usable space.  Thirdly, the filesystem takes up space too - a 60GB NTFS partition may really  be 59-ish GB usable.

Ultimately I think this is a case of an odd-size USB stick having only 62GB usable space, not 68GB that's being advertised.  Which means you really *don't* have the amount of space you think you do available.

Comment: interesting in theory but I've had it for about a month, maybe 2, and I can no longer put the same files on it that were on it before, which for me is the acid test that something's wrong. Furthermore, I'm not confused about the size: you can see yourself that there's a clear discrepancy between how big thunar thinks the drive is, how much space it thinks it being used, and how much if free. Even if it WAS 64gb minus a teeny bit of file system (surely nowhere near 1gb of filesystem for a thumb drive) then that still wouldn't explain the ~12gb missing.

Comment: for precision: it was bought by my cousin to put photos & videos of our wedding on. Those files are 60.9gb total. I've used it maybe 5 times for other purposes and now want to put the original files back on there and they no longer fit. Conceptually this is a damage issue but there I know of no way to verify this. Also it seems very odd that gparted & thunar are reporting the total size of all the items as 52.3gb but the space used as 64gb (66.4 - 2.7). This is a clear calculation disparity. One of them is wrong.